# What is the opposite of polyglot programming?

Tags: terminology

Polyglot programming is when a system, such as a web application, is constructed using many different languages. A common combination is Java+JSP+JavaScript.

What is the word that is the exact opposite of polyglot programming? That is, a system is coded purely in one language?

Comment: monoglot programming =)

Comment: monogamous programming. now that is commitment

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal: a web application, for example. Wikipedia is more precise: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)

Comment: Coherent programming. (BTW: Poly generally means many, not merely  more than one.) ((Monolingual))

Comment: The word 'glot' seems to mean 'speech' or 'language', and there is a bunch of prefixes that can be used with it: http://wordinfo.info/unit/921

According to that link, you can refer to a single-language system as beeing 'monoglottic', so 'monoglot programming' could well be the correct answer. I will go with that, thank you guys!

Comment: I think this is a terminology question, nothing else (so I changed the tagging). Given there are over 1000 terminology-tagged questions (at time of this comment), I wonder why this question is closed as off-topic? My reasoning is that I find it highly *practical* to use the correct terminology in *the programming profession* (referring to the current community-defined on-topic scope).     Not fit for an answer, (but maybe useful for a non-native speaker): I usually hear people state that program 'foo' was written in `pure 'bar'` (where 'bar' is programming language they speak about).

Answer (score 2):

monolingual programming? =) A very rare thing indeed.